# Hadoop Command for Running a MapReduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a jar called WordCountMain.jar. I would like to run this jar using hadoop command in multimode cluster.

but my user id is tagged to queue name as "omega". so if I run the above jar using the below command then I am getting a error that indicates that my id is not having submit_job access.

```
hadoop jar WordCountMain.jar /user/cloudera/inputs/words.txt /user/cloudera/output
```

So the above command not works in multimode cluster,but it works in single node CDH3 cluster

So ,My question is How do i include the queue name while running the above jar.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");

    job.setJarByClass(WordCountCombinerMain.class);

    Path inputFilePath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputFilePath = new Path(args[1]);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(CWordCountMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(CWordCountCombiner1.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CWordCountCombiner1.class);
    //job.setReducerClass(CwordCountReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    job.submit();
```

Pls give me the method name for adding the queue name in driver class.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add a snippet of the exception?

perhaps try setting the hadoop user name will resolve the issue.

e.g.

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=your_hadoop_username
```

PS: I couldn't comment, hence I added as answer note!

Comment: i would like to know how to set the queue name in  configuration class of mapreduce.

Comment: I tried setting the queue name by using the below lines and it worked.. but how do i set the queue name using new APIJobConf conf1 = new JobConf(); 
  conf1.setQueueName("omega");
  Job job = new Job(conf1,"word count");

Comment: Try setting it in the code  like this: 
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename","omega");

Or at execution time like this:
-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=omega

Comment: I tried the below . but the same error
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf,"word count");
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename","omega");
job.setJarByClass(WordCountCombinerMain.class);

 ERROR ipc.RPC: FailoverProxy: Failing this Call: submitJob for error(RemoteException): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User mytra cannot perform operation SUBMIT_JOB on queue default.

Answer (score 0):

You didnot give the classname

```
hadoop jar WordCountMain.jar **className**  /user/cloudera/inputs/words.txt /user/cloudera/output
```

like

```
**hadoop jar /usr/joe/wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /usr/joe/wordcount/input /usr/joe/wordcount/output**
```